# python transform a string input matrix to 0-1 binary input matrix for logistic regression like R

Tags: python, r, scikit-learn, sparse-matrix, logistic-regression

I'm doing some logistic regression with Python using pandas+numpy+scikit-learn. However in scikit-learn build-in logistic regression model, it doesn't allow a string input, but I'd like to do something like in R which converts a str column input directly to several sparse columns with 0-1 binary input.

for example in R, if i do this:

```
n=100
x<-1:n
epsilon<-rnorm(n)
g<-sample(c("A","B","C","D"),n,replace=T)
g<-as.factor(g)
m <- as.data.frame(model.matrix(~g-1))
fit=glm(x~-1+g)
```

There will be no problem, but in python, it throw an error because It can't take str input.

Is there any existing method to do this? Because I don't know Cython and I don't want to re-write this in python level...

I hope I'm clear enough here.
Any helps?

Thanks a lot

Comment: Potential duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/q/10196860/2167315

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use scikit-learn instead of patsy / statsmodel you can alternatively use the [OneHotEncoder](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/preprocessing.html#encoding-categorical-features). The example uses integer categories but it also works on string categories.